# mod_rewrite - RewriteCond QUERY_STRING does not catch query when there is one

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I am struggling with mod_rewrite and couldn't figure out the reasons it works that strange way.

It's about finding the best way for handling friendly URLs.

Let's assume the domain is trojka-poligrafia.pl/

Effect to achieve is: whatever occurs after query ?s= is friendly link parameter that should get rewrited, eg:

```
trojka-poligrafia.pl/whateva?s=portfolio   ->   trojka-poligrafia.pl/portfolio

trojka-poligrafia.pl/index.php?s=portfolio   ->   trojka-poligrafia.pl/portfolio
```

even the mess like:

```
trojka-poligrafia.pl/whateva;params,there,are?s=portfolio;klient,15   ->   trojka-poligrafia.pl/portfolio;klient,15
```

All the above work properly, but there is one query RewriteCond can't catch/handle:

```
trojka-poligrafia.pl/?s=portfolio -> trojka-poligrafia.pl/portfolio
```

This redirect never happens and I can't find any reason why.

.htaccess rules handling the redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Maybe some earlier or later directives are responsible for that?
all .htaccess contents:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^trojka-poligrafia\.pl.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1 [R=301,L]

#catch query and translate into real friendly link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1? [R=301,L]

#translate friendly link for php, no visitor redirecting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ \?s=$1 [L]
```

Maybe `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php(.*)` is the problem? Or mod_rewrite forsees somehow that I'm going to redirect query back and forth and skips the procedure? Still it shouldn't as second redirect happens only on server-side...

After Justin's comment I have finally found working way for making URL friendly:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^trojka-poligrafia\.pl.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

but after redirecting, nevermind next rules, they generate errors. I have tried multiple combinations and none of these work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$
```

without $ sign as well, without ^ as well, as well as with QUERY_STRING, and multiple combinations of rewriterules, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \?s=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ s=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

as well as .+ instead of .* and %1 instead of $1....... all of them return error.

After a bit of trying I assume this one should work:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^trojka-poligrafia\.pl.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trojka-poligrafia.pl/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \?s=%1 [L]
```

but it doesn't... Last rewriterule must be the reason, still don't know why it communicates with the browser, when it is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anydomain.com/\?s=%1 [L]
```

it works properly. Using [L,PT] doesn't change a thing.

Comment: `All the above work properly`. I don't think it works for `trojka-poligrafia.pl/index.php?s=portfolio` since your rule does not apply if existing file/folder is requested. Simply remove your 2 `RewriteCond` before your rule. You have also some syntax errors in your code

Comment: OK, I get the point. Actually didn't think about excluding index.php. Is it safe to remove these directives you have pointed? Syntax error - you mean last RewriteRule? or the first one?

Comment: What is more: after removing these 2 directives browser detects wrong redirect for any request for trojka-poligrafia.pl

Comment: What is more2: after removing these 2 directives, nevermind the further rules, params or solutions, all I get is error message.